# Prove: The union of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

The problem is to prove that the union of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is open.

```
However, the only definitions that I have to work with are:
```

A set is closed if it is not equal to the empty set and if contains all of its limit points.

A point $p$ in the set $A$ is a limit point of $A$ if all the points in $A$ converge to $p$.

```
With those definitions, I have surmised that:
```

An open set is a non-empty set that does not contain (all of) its limit points.

```
I also know:
```

A union of sets is a set that contains all the elements that are in any of the sets in the union.

Below is what I currently have for the proof. Please tell me if this is a sufficient proof, if you see any mistakes, etc.

```
Proof:
```

Let $U$ be the set of an arbitrary union of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

I.e., $U$ = $\cup$ $X_n$ where $X$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $U$ is comprised of subsets that do not contain their limit points, then $U$, the union of these subsets, does not contain its limit points.

Therefore, $U$ is open.

```
Is this a sufficient proof?
```

Comment: First of all, usually the empty set is also considered closed (and open). Also, you are lacking a correct definition of open (and open is *not* the negation of closed) -  and finally, the union of sets not containing all limit points may indeed contain all limit points (it could be all of $\mathbb R$, for example)

Comment: Your definition of an open set is not correct (if you want your openness definition to correspond to the typical one used).

Comment: So I have the incorrect definition of open set. Thank you.

Comment: But wait, I looked on Wikipedia and the definition of open set is: "a set is open if it doesn't contain any of its boundary points." How is this different from my proposed definition?

Comment: As long as we're pointing out errors in the definitions, I might as well mention that your definition of "limit point" is also wrong (or perhaps meaningless).  I strongly suggest that you go back to wherever you got the definitions from and take them as they are, not attempting to rewrite them. (For example, in connection with your comment 9 minutes ago, "boundary point" is not the same as "limit point"; check the definitions.)

Comment: "An open set is a non-empty set that does not contain (all of) its limit points." This is false. As said before a set is open if its complement is closed. And this is not the same as asking that it is not open.
In particular, there are sets which neither closed nor open. Could you also check your definitions and replace them with correct ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a definition of either open or closed sets, usually you define the other type of set by saying that an open set is the complement of a closed set (or equivalently, a closed set is the complement of an open set). So if you accept this axiom, and you have a definition of a closed set, then you need to show that the intersection of two closed sets is closed and then you will have that the union of two open sets is open.

Comment: So this is a proof by contraposition? So to restate your points: 1) Say that an open set is the complement of a closed set. 2) Prove that the union of closed sets is closed. 3) Once #2 is proven, this implies that the union of open subsets is open.

Comment: @user3025403 Basically yes, except that you want to prove that the INTERSECTION of closed sets is closed, not the union. Then when you take the complement you will get that the union of open sets is open. Using your definition of "closed", it should be pretty easy to prove that the intersection of two closed sets is closed.

Comment: And it is not a proof by contraposition here. Just by looking at the complements of points in the set.